# p command in Funge-98 quines

Tags: discussion, quine

Should the p command be considered cheating in Funge-98 quines?

I'm asking because:
Unlike the g command it does not read source code, so it doesn't break "No reading source code" rule.
But it does modify source code so it may be considered cheating?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no Quine rule against modifying the source code. I don't know enough about that command to say whether that makes it valid though.

Comment: Can you provide a description or link to what those commands do? Thanks.

Comment: As long as the output is a quine of the original code, not the modified code, using `p` is fine

Comment: @mbomb007 https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98#Instructions here's the full list of instructions.

Comment: Ah, so they're like the ><> commands. Got it.